# Unity configure by convention

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is it possible to configure the Unity Dependency Injection framework to resolve by convention. So in other words if I have an ICustomerRepository when it tries to resolve this it will first look to see if there are any registered types and if not will then by convention try and resolve CustomerRepository class.

This would save a lot of repetitive coding.

Comment: Check this blog post:
[Convention-based Registration Extension for Unity](http://www.ctrl-shift-b.com/2009/06/convention-based-registration-extension.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unity 3 has now support for registration by convention. For more info and examples, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec23).

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Unity Auto Registration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) project which does much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Thomas Pedersen](http://thedersen.com) has built the [Unity Configuration API](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration) for conventional based configuration of Unity.

You can get the [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/UnityConfiguration) or the [source](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration).